# How to convert .service tag to TypeScript command

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, service, module

I'm trying to convert my AngularJS program to Angular, which means my code needs to be converted to TypeScript. I'm having problems with the .service part of my code.

I've already tried to just eliminate the .service already. I've also tried to rewrite the code completely to fit TS, but that wasn't working.

```js
//  updated AngularJS code to fit TypeScript (mostly)
('resumeApp') 
// next line "service" needs to be changed
.service('PositionService', function($http) {
  // tslint:disable-next-line: only-arrow-functions
  this.getPositions = async function() {
    let data = [];
    await $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'http://localhost:4200/'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
      const positions = response.data;
      // tslint:disable-next-line: prefer-for-of
      for (let x = 0; x < positions.length; x++) {
        if (positions[x].availible) {
        data.push(positions[x].position);
        }
      }
    }, function errorCallback() {
      data = undefined;
    });
    return data;
  };
});
```

The error message I get is that the "property 'service' does not exist on type 'resumeApp'".

Comment: `('resumeApp')` is just a string...

Comment: @jonrsharpe it was initially "angular.module('resumeApp')". Didi I convert that incorrectly then?

Comment: You haven't converted it at all, just deleted some words.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Then do you have some suggestions of what I could do to fix this problem?

Comment: Conversion to Angular isn't just switching to TypeScript. I'd recommend reading the docs, e.g. https://angular.io/guide/upgrade

Comment: @jonrsharpe alright thank you!